# Правильно ли я разбил класс на подклассы

Tags: android, классы

У меня есть класс примерной структуры

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Этот класс уже занимает несколько сотен строк кода, поэтому его реализацию методов я разбить на мелкие кусочки. **И вот что у меня получилось**, логику меню я перенес в другой класс.

```
class BrowserActivity : AppCompatActivity(){

    lateinit var mMenu: Menu
    lateinit var mWebView : WebView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.m_browser)

        mWebView = findViewById(R.id.mbrowser)
        mMenu = Menu(this, this, mWebView) //context, activity, ...
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
       return mMenu.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        return mMenu.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
```

Я хотел бы узнать, правильно ли я делаю, что данный класс разбил таким образом?

Comment: реализацию колбэков не имеет большого смысла выносить в другой класс - это и так реализация при вызове из другого класса, а прямое назначение активити - обрабатывать контролы (в ланном случае создание и управление меню). в другой класс нужно вынести все, что напрямую не относится к работе с контролами - всякое получение данных, их обработка, расчеты и все такое.

Comment: @pavlofff получается что всякие переопределенные методы Activity я не трогая, а только в них передаю обработанные данные при помощь скажем mvp?